# Gitian build compile errors

Tags: debian

I am doing altcoin compiling for make windows build in debian OS in VirtualBox in Windows10 laptop.

I did at terminal below,

```
./bin/gbuild --commit funcoin=v0.8 ../funcoin/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-win32.yml
```

But error says,

---

> debian@debian:~/gitian-builder$ ./bin/gbuild --commit
>   bitcoinessence=v0.8.1
>   ../BitcoinEssence/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-win32.yml
>   Initialized empty Git repository in
>   /home/debian/gitian-builder/inputs/bitcoinessence/.git/ Username for
>   'https://github.com': leegod Password for 'https://leegod@github.com':
>   remote: Counting objects: 903, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>   (722/722), done. remote: Total 903 (delta 174), reused 884 (delta
>   162), pack-reused 0 Receiving objects: 100% (903/903), 36.51 MiB |
>   1.57 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (174/174), done. From https://github.com/leegod/BitcoinEssence  * [new tag]         v0.8
>   -> v0.8  * [new tag]         v0.8.1     -> v0.8.1  * [new branch]      master     -> master
>   --- Building for precise amd64 --- Stopping target if it is up Making a new image copy sudo: unable to resolve host gitian stdin: is not a
>   tty Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done The
>   following packages will be REMOVED:   rsyslog ubuntu-minimal 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded. After
>   this operation, 1289 kB disk space will be freed. (Reading database
>   ... 16076 files and directories currently installed.) Removing
>   ubuntu-minimal ... Removing rsyslog ... initctl: Unable to connect to
>   Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection
>   refused Processing triggers for ureadahead ... Adding 'local diversion
>   of /sbin/initctl to /sbin/initctl.distrib' Adding 'local diversion of
>   /usr/bin/ischroot to /usr/bin/ischroot.distrib' Adding 'local
>   diversion of /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d to /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d.distrib'
>   Starting target Checking if target is up Preparing build environment
>   Updating apt-get repository (log in var/install.log) Installing
>   additional packages (log in var/install.log) Upgrading system, may
>   take a while Creating package manifest stdin: is not a tty Creating
>   build script (var/build-script) Running build script (log in
>   var/build.log) ./bin/gbuild:21:in `system!': failed to run on-target
>   setarch x86_64 bash -x < var/build-script > var/build.log 2>&1
>   (RuntimeError) from ./bin/gbuild:163:in`build_one_configuration' from
>   ./bin/gbuild:300:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' from
>   ./bin/gbuild:295:in`each' from ./bin/gbuild:295:in `block in <main>'
>   from ./bin/gbuild:293:in`each' from ./bin/gbuild:293:in `'
>   debian@debian:~/gitian-builder$